# Amazon Comprehend Medical returning FILTERED values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-comprehend

Amazon Comprehend Medical returns values labeled as [FILTERED]. I have a rails 5.2 app and have installed the `aws-sdk` gem. I am now trying an API call through the rails console and get a return JSON. But most of the values get returned as [FILTERED]. Any idea what causes this?

I have scoured the AWS documentation but can't seem to find an answer to this.

```rb
class Comprehend 
 require 'aws-sdk-comprehendmedical'  

  client = Aws::ComprehendMedical::Client.new
  resp = client.detect_entities({
   text: "45 yr old male with chestpain and SOB BP 120/70", # required
    })
  puts(resp)

end
```

This is the result when running this as Comprehend.new in the console.

```
{
    :entities=>[
        {
            :id=>"[FILTERED]",
            :begin_offset=>0,
            :end_offset=>2,
            :score=>0.9994971752166748,
            :text=>"[FILTERED]",
            :category=>"PROTECTED_HEALTH_INFORMATION",
            :type=>"[FILTERED]",
            :traits=>[],
            :attributes=>nil
        },
        {
            :id=>"[FILTERED]",
            :begin_offset=>20,
            :end_offset=>29,
            :score=>0.9164832830429077,
            :text=>"[FILTERED]",
            :category=>"MEDICAL_CONDITION",
            :type=>"[FILTERED]",
            :traits=>[],
            :attributes=>nil
        },
        {
            :id=>"[FILTERED]",
            :begin_offset=>34,
            :end_offset=>37,
            :score=>0.8974254131317139,
            :text=>"[FILTERED]",
            :category=>"MEDICAL_CONDITION",
            :type=>"[FILTERED]",
            :traits=>[],
            :attributes=>nil
        },
        {
            :id=>"[FILTERED]",
            :begin_offset=>38,
            :end_offset=>40,
            :score=>0.8211551904678345,
            :text=>"[FILTERED]",
            :category=>"TEST_TREATMENT_PROCEDURE",
            :type=>"[FILTERED]",
            :traits=>[],
            :attributes=>[
                {
                    :type=>"[FILTERED]",
                    :score=>0.9983691573143005,
                    :relationship_score=>1.0,
                    :id=>"[FILTERED]",
                    :begin_offset=>41,
                    :end_offset=>47,
                    :text=>"[FILTERED]",
                    :traits=>[]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    :unmapped_attributes=>[],
    :pagination_token=>nil
}
```

Comment: I believe those are only `[FILTERED]` for the console output to protect sensitive information (so that you don't have PII or PHI floating around in your console logs). The values are probably actually present in the API response.

Comment: @jvillian, you are correct! Once I put the results in a view it all shows up correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended behavior for sensitive information when printing to the rails console or when being used in logs.

The actual value is there and can be used programmatically, but the aws-sdk has an interesting feature called log filtering that they use to hide sensitive information in logs and the console. Rails has a similar feature you can use, below are links to the rails documentation as well as the code in the aws-sdk ruby gem for filtering sensitive information:

- [Action Controller Overview — Ruby on Rails Guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#log-filtering)
- [aws-sdk-ruby/param_filter.rb](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/d4a50ffae6054b3837ec929ad685375358713231/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/log/param_filter.rb)

Answer (score 0):

to whoever encounter this issue with aws api, just use to_h instead

```
puts resp.to_h
```

and if you need it as json just

```
puts resp.to_h.to_json
```